# Trigger to prevent record saving without attachment

Tags: apex, trigger, picklist, attachment

I am new to Salesforce and trying to write a trigger with the picklist values yes or no. If value 'YES' is selected then trigger should fire and display "an attachment is required", if the value is 'NO' should allow saving the record.

We already have a trigger on Account object which is part of managed package, now can I write another trigger on the same Account object?

Comment: You cannot require a child record on insert.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write your own trigger on the Account object along side any Managed triggers that are there on the object too.

### Insert

On `insert` of an `Account` record you can check for the value of `YES`, query for related `Attachment` records and throw an error when none are found but that is the extent of it.

There will never be an `Attachment` related to the `Account` during an `insert` operation because the `Account` needs to exist prior to associating the `Attachment` to it.

You would be better off to skip a query for the attachments and simply prevent the insert of an Account with this picklist having a value of `YES`. This can be done with a Validation Rule as well as in trigger code.

### Update

On `update` of the `Account` object your scenario becomes more valuable.

The trigger code during `update` could inspect the related attachments and ensure that the user had uploaded an `Attachment` prior to changing the picklist value to `YES` and saving the `Account`.

Comment: Mark thanks for your response, I am trying to do same for custom object as well. I would appreciate if you can paste code here, thanks

Comment: trigger Sandals on currency__c (before insert, before update) {
    
    for(currency__c c : Trigger.new){
        if (c.customfield__c = 'YES'){
            c.currency__c = 'Missing Attachement';
        }
        else if{
            c.customfield__c == 'NO';
        }
            insert c;
        }